# Complement in $\Bbb C$ of a compact subset of $\Bbb R$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology

Let A be a compact subset of R, the real numbers. Prove that the complement of A in the complex numbers C is connected.

My thoughts: If A is compact then it is contained in a finite union. So if it's complement in C was disconnected it would imply C was disconnected-contradicton

Comment: Is this showing that $\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R$ is connected? Then you are in trouble, no?

Comment: nope b/c the complement has a non-empty intersection with the finite union of open sets.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful. It isn't clear what you mean by "a finite union." Also, your reasoning doesn't work--the complement of $\Bbb R$ in $\Bbb C$ is disconnected, even though $\Bbb C$ isn't.

Here's an alternative approach: Suppose $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ such that $\Bbb C\setminus A$ is disconnected. Note that $\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R$ is contained in $\Bbb C\setminus A,$ so the upper open half-plane must lie in a connected component of $\Bbb C\setminus A,$ as must the lower open half-plane. Use this to show that $A=\Bbb R.$ *Hint*: If not, then there is some real $z$ lying in $\Bbb C\setminus A.$ Now, consider the following (which is a good exercise to prove):

> **Lemma**: If $X$ is a connected subset of a topological space, and $\overline X$ denotes its closure, then for any set $Y$ with $X\subseteq Y\subseteq\overline X,$ we have that $Y$ is connected.

In particular, since the upper open half-plane $H^+$ is connected, then $H^+\cup\{z\}$ is connected. Likewise, $H^-\cup\{z\}$ is connected, so since the union of two nondisjoint connected sets is connected, then $(\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R)\cup\{z\}$ is connected. Since the closure of this set is all of $\Bbb C,$ then the result follows from the Lemma. (Do you see how?)

Hence, we have a stronger result: If $A$ is *any proper subset* of $\Bbb R$ (in which compact subsets of $\Bbb R$ are included), then its complement in $\Bbb C$ is connected.

---

**P.S.**: It is tempting to try to proceed as in your (now-deleted) answer below, and say that if $\Bbb C\setminus A$ were disconnected, then it is the disjoint union of two non-empty closed sets $E$ and $F,$ and so $\Bbb C$ is the disjoint union of the three non-empty closed sets $E,F,$ and $A,$ and so we reach the contradictory conclusion that $\Bbb C$ is disconnected.

The problem with that approach is that we must distinguish between sets that are (relatively) closed in $\Bbb C\setminus A$ and sets that are closed (in $\Bbb C$). The particular case $A=\Bbb R$ shows us how this reasoning falls apart. Indeed, $\Bbb C\setminus A$ is the disjoint union of $H^+$ and $H^-,$ both of which are non-empty and (relatively) closed. Since $\Bbb R$ is closed (in $\Bbb C$), it would seem by the reasoning above--without the parenthetical remarks--that $\Bbb C$ *is* the disjoint union of three closed non-empty sets. But neither $H^+$ nor $H^-$ is closed in $\Bbb C,$ so those distinctions are critical!

Comment: why if $C/A=U\cup V$,then $H^{+}\subset U$ or V

Comment: Well, if not, then both $H^+\cap U$ and $H^+\cap V$ would be open and non-empty, which would tell us what about $H^+$?

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts:

Whenever possible, I prefer dealing with path-connected spaces to connected spaces, because I can more easily visualize it.  If $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact, then there's an $R > 0$ such that $A \subset [-R, R]$.  Now if we have two points $z, w \in \mathbb{C} \setminus A$, then we have a couple of easy cases:

1. If only one of the two points happens to lie on $\mathbb{R}$ (say it's z), we can move vertically from $z$ to $\Re z + \Im w$ and then move along that line to $w$.
2. If they happen to have the same nonzero imaginary part, then just connect them linearly.
3. If they happen to have differing nonzero imaginary parts, just move horizontally (left or right) until you're passed $[-R,R]$, move vertically to the right half plane, and then you're free to move linearly.
4. If they both happen to lie on $\mathbb{R}$, move vertically from one point into a half plane, move horizontally until you have the appropriate real coordinate, and then move vertically again.